# Retrieve parameters from url with XPages

Tags: xpages

I created a page with XPages and jquery mobile.
I passed in a link to a page parameter.

The link that is generated is as follows:

```
http://myserver/mydb.nsf/Test.xsp#subpage?parameter=B
```

I tried using different methods to retrieve the data you get is the past, but not able to retrieve the parameter.

```
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var request = exCon.getRequest(); // This is the actual HTTP servlet request...
var paramValue = request.getParameter("parameter");
aaa = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURL();
bbb = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI();
ccc = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
ddd = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getQueryString();
var url:XSPUrl;
url = context.getUrl();
var tagname = url.getParameter('parameter');
prova = ddd.getParameter('parameter');
print("Request: " + request)
print("URL2: " + url);
print("URL: " + aaa);
print("URL3: " + bbb);
print("URL4: " + ccc);
print("URL5: " + ddd);
print("Parametro3 : " + prova);
print("Parametro2 : " + tagname);
print("Parametro: " + paramValue);
```

Doing a bit of debug with the consol I saw that the url that is shown is:

```
http://myserver/mydb.nsf/Test.xsp
```

How do I retrieve the value of the parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `param.get("parameter")` yet?

Also, the #fragment should be at the end of the url after the parmeters so it would look like

```
http://myserver/mydb.nsf/Test.xsp?parameter=B#subpage
```

Comment: ok what you say is right, typing the link manually, everything seems to work.
If I go to use the link on the website does not get any results, I get turned over on page # without first being written parameter.

the url is composed: href = "?parameter=b#subpage"
Of course if you use <xp:link> the link is written as #subpage?parameter=b

Answer (score 2):

Every fragment of an URL after the hashtag will not be transferred with the HTTP request and is not available for the server.

The Server only receives the URL part before the #, that is why you never will get this information. There are different ways to send the data to the server:
You can add a hidden field or you can just append them to the URL before the hashtag (and access them via External Context), f.e. http://myserver/dB.nsf/test.xsp/subpage/b/

Answer (score 0):

You can't get to the hash part using server requests.